# Side menu showing empty page Ionic/angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, sidebar

I am trying to add an side menu but what happens is that the top header shows and the page content disappears. I am not sure how to fix it. Can someone please assist me?

in my routes

```
$stateProvider

   .state('jobStore', {
      url: '/homePage',
      views: {
      'side-menu21': {
         templateUrl: 'templates/homePage/jobStore.html',
         controller: 'jobStoreCtrl'       
      }
    }
  })

 .state('menu', {
    url: '/side-menu21',
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu/menu.html',
    abstract:true
  })
```

my sidebar is called menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
            <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="side-menu21"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left" id="side-menu21">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <div class="title">Menu</div>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content padding="false" class="side-menu-left has-header">
            <ion-list id="menu-null" class=" ">
                <ion-item id="menu-list-item1" ui-sref="menu.home" menu-close="" class="  ">Home</ion-item>
                <ion-item id="menu-list-item2" ui-sref="menu.cart" menu-close="" class="  ">Cart</ion-item>
                <ion-item id="menu-list-item3" ui-sref="menu.cloud" menu-close="" class="  ">Cloud</ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

am i missing some addition in other pages ?

Comment: @MohanGopi where do I write that?

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the code here: [Ionic Play - Side Menu](http://play.ionic.io/app/26eff22020a5).

Your `menu` state is the first page's state so your `jobStore` should be a child of this state like `menu.jobStore`.

In the code, I am activating that sate in the `run` block using `$state.go('menu.jobStore');`.

Comment: I am not sure i understand, I put the code <ion-side-menus> in the menu.html, then in the main page, i put the class bar header with ng-toggleLeft(). After I put the toggle function in my jobstore function. But i noticed that when I put a view in my controller the page goes blank, But without the view the button is there but it doesnt click